# Solve inequality with absolute values $|3-5x|-|2x+1|\ge|x-1|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

How can I solve this:
$$|3-5x|-|2x+1|\ge|x-1|$$
$x=3/5,-1/2,1$ is when the absolutes is $0$. 
I received $x=3/2$ when the equality holds.
But for every $x$ the equation $|3-5x|-|2x+1|>|x-1|$.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just study the signs of each term in absolute value, subdivide $\mathbb R$ in sub-intervals where those signs are constant, and rewrite the inequation on each of this subinterval.

Comment: Can you write one example of  term in absolute?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x):=|3-5x|-|2x+1|-|x-1|$ is piecewise linear and the "corners" are located where one of the arguments goes to zero, i.e. $x=-\dfrac12,\dfrac35,1$.

Evaluating the function at these points (using the appropriate sign in $|t|=\pm t$), we get

$$f\left(-\frac12\right)=4,f\left(\frac35\right)=-\frac{13}5,f\left(1\right)=-1$$

so that the function has two roots, one in $\left(-\dfrac12,\dfrac35\right)$ and one in $(1,\infty)$.

Now, expressing the function in these ranges, we get

$$\left(-\dfrac12,\dfrac35\right)\to3-5x-2x-1\ge1-x\implies6x\le1,$$
$$\left(1,\infty\right)\to5x-3-2x-1\ge x-1\implies2x\ge3.$$

Comment: I did not study functions yet

Comment: @babushka: you did without knowing, the absolute value is a function.